# Cygwin and Eclipse Helios setup

Tags: c++, eclipse, cygwin, helios

I am trying to learn C++ with Cygwin and Eclipse Helios.
I got all the development tools under Cygwin installed; and installed the CDT package for Helios.

The problem is I don't see an option to create a C++ project from makefile or any other option. I can only see options for a C Project, C++ project and a new project from existing source code.

Here is what I referred to:

- [Eclipse seminar](http://adobedev.adobe.acrobat.com/p20583465/?launcher=false&fcsContent=true&pbMode=normal)
- [Developing applications using the Eclipse C/C++ Development Toolkit](http://ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-stlcdt/)

Questions:

1. Is there any clear guide to setup Eclipse for Cygwin?
2. Am I missing something in the setup?

any other suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: In Cygwin installation, make sure to at least pick the following packages under Development: gcc-core, gcc-g++, gdb, make

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you asking how to setup GCC in cygwin + Eclipse? [How about this tutorial](http://homepage.cs.uri.edu/courses/fall2007/csc406/Handouts/eclipseTutorial.pdf)?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html) tutorial to be a very good source. It was `almost`perfect, apart that one more path needed to be add to the folder containing `cygstdc++-6.dll` which prevented anything to be printed on console. So, add to the `Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes GNU C++` the path to the missing dll folder: `${CYGWIN_HOME}/usr/i686-pc-cygwin/sys-root/usr/bin`.

Comment: Please do not post [duplicate answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/206345). Instead, consider other actions that could help future users find the answer they need, as described in the linked post.

Comment: duplicate to which answer because i didnt realize.